# C++: Преобразование текущего символа string в int

Tags: c++

Нужно сравнить два числа, **количество цифр** которых будет равняться вплоть до 10^6 (Тип данных записан как string). Какие помимо этого способа существуют преобразования текущего символа строки в int:

int k = int(s[i]) - 48;

Comment: А зачем вам вообще переводить что-то в целые числа? Смотрите на длину. Если длины разные (ведущие нули мы с негодованием отметаем :)) - то все понятно. Если одинаковые - сравниваем s[i] и t[i], скажем. Или просто лексикографически сравниваем строки...

Comment: Допустим, я так и делаю. И вот по времени сравнение по одному символу дело утомляющее. А если у нас дан целый массив таких чисел, который нужно отсортировать. 

Как можно будет оптимизировать код? Особенно волнует: можно ли брать куски string и преобразовывать в int?

Comment: `string a, b; if (a < b) ...`

Comment: Может имеет смысл заменить `string`, на скажем, массив `unsigned int`? Т.е. перейти от десятичных чисел  к числам из цифр по основанию 2^32

Comment: Во-первых, `int k = s[i] - '0';` (а не `48`). Во-вторых, а зачем вам понадобилось искать какие-то еще способы преобразования? Чем этот плох?

Comment: @AnT, почему `s[i] - '0'` лучше чем `s[i] - 48`?

Comment: @wololo: А что такое вообще за магическая константа `48` и откуда она взялась?

Comment: @AnT, ASCII-код нуля? Или полагаться на то, что `'0' == 48` вообще говоря опасно?

Comment: @wololo: Именно так. Ни в С, ни в С++ не гарантируется `'0' == 48`. Гарантируется только, что цифры идут подряд по возрастанию без пропусков `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`... и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> количество цифр которых будет равняться вплоть до 10^6

Не надо их в число преобразовывать. Ни один встроенный тип не обеспечит такую точность.

> Нужно сравнить два числа ... Тип данных записан как string

Надо взять две строки

- у обеих убрать лидирующие нули, если они допускаются
- если строки имеют разную длину, то та, что короче, содержит меньшее число
- в случае одинаковой длины надо сравнить строки лексикографически

Всё :)

Answer (score -3):

На этот вопрос уже давно есть ответ и не один, и не два. Даже тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/7664227/3654943

`std::stoi( str )`

Comment: И как представить в `int` (тип, возвращаемый `stoi`) число, записанное миллионом (*`"количество цифр которых будет равняться вплоть до 10^6"`*) цифр?

Comment: В комментарии по той-же ссылке: `long stol(string)`, тыж программист, ты пишешь на с++, ты обязан знать такие вещи. Это примитивные вещи, это то с чего начинается изучения языка!

Comment: А вы, похоже, еще нет. Сколько *двоичных разрядов* в long? (конечно, в случае С++ это зависит от системы, но на данный момент не больше 64). А в вопросе речь о **миллионе десятичных** (для программиста важна внимательность к деталям)

Comment: В чем проблема? С каких пор 64 байт мало, чтоб хранить значение в миллион?

Comment: вы серьезно или дурачитесь? Миллион -- это **10^6**, а ***миллион цифр***  даст **10^1000000**

Comment: Ну ок, использовать bigint. Взять любую имплементацию и скормить ей строку хоть в миллиард символов. Но автору хватит и stoi для сравнения своих цифр.

Comment: Даже в 64 байта влезет всего-то сотни полторы десятичных цифр, а 64-байтного целочисленного встроенного типа в С++ нет и никогда не было.  64-битные есть, но они в 8 раз уже.

Comment: Почему это не ответ-ссылка: разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72918/discussion-on-answer-by-profesor08-c----string-).

Comment: tl;dr будущим проверяющим: ответ отвечает (ну, хотя бы пытается) на вопрос непосредственно последней строчкой, а ссылка лишь как источник/дополнение. Убедительная просьба не рекомендовать удаление по причине "ответ-ссылка". Она здесь не подходит.

Comment: @D-side: вот поэтому надпись "Выглядит нормально" в очереди проверок вводит в заблуждение. И даже объяснение: "**Выглядит нормально** если ответ в порядке" только запутывает. А mouseover "ответ не выглядит низкокачественным" окончательно запутывает. Настоящее объяснение этой кнопки должно быть: "ответ является честной попыткой показать решение (даже если оно и неправильное)".

Comment: @jfs [есть такая беда](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32106352#32106352).

Comment: @D-side: [2015]: [Следует ли удалять неправильные ответы (в очереди проверок), которые являются честной попыткой ответить на вопрос?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1435/23044)